# How can I synchronize the To do Ubuntu app and calendar with google

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, calendar, taskbar

In 18.04 the google to do list and calendar tasks where automatically synchronized with the to-do app and calendar, but this is not happening with 20.04.01 (my google accounts are already "registered" to Ubuntu)
Is there anything I can do?
Thanks

Comment: can you try to remove the account and add it back?